# ​Bedeutung von "der er" am Anfang eines Nebensatzes, wo sich "der" und "er" scheinbar auf dieselbe Person beziehen

Tags: subordinate-clause

Ich würde mich freuen, wenn jemand mir erklären könnte, warum im folgenden Abschnitt aus Neuer Vahr Süd (von Sven Regener) "der er" steht. Ich würde denken, dass "der" allein reichen würde und richtig wäre.

> Der Spieß winkte ihm mit den Worten »So so, Sie sind das« gleich
> durch, »gehen Sie gleich rein, der Hauptmann wartet schon lange genug
> auf Sie«, sagte er, bevor Frank überhaupt grüßen und Meldung machen
> konnte, denn das hatte er vorgehabt, die Sache war ihm nicht geheuer,
> da wollte er keinen Anschiß riskieren, Fahnenjunker Tietz ist das
> eine, hatte er gedacht, bevor er das Zimmer des Spieß betreten hatte,
> bei dem kennt man sich aus, aber der Spieß und der Kompaniechef, das
> ist noch einmal eine andere Liga, hatte er gedacht, er war höchst
> unruhig gewesen, als er an die Tür des Spieß geklopft hatte, wer weiß,
> was die wollen, hatte er gedacht, aber jetzt, als der Spieß ihn, **der
> er** gerade gehorsam Meldung machen wollte, einfach lässig
> weiterschickte, schämte er sich ein bißchen, es war ihm peinlich, daß
> er freiwillig den Gruß und die Meldung »Pionier Lehmann, melde mich
> wie befohlen« hatte loswerden wollen, er hatte sich diesen Satz sogar
> auf dem Weg zur Kompanie extra zurechtgelegt und ein bißchen geprobt,
> man muß aufpassen, daß man kein Schleimer wird und jeden Scheiß
> mitmacht, dachte er und öffnete die Tür zum Büro des Kompaniechefs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wenn im Deutschen ein Personalpronomen (wie "er") mit einem Relativsatz beschrieben wird, muss das Personalpronomen im selben Kasus wie das Relativpronomen auf das Relativpronomen folgen. Man hat also zwei aufeinanderfolgende Wörter, die das gleiche beschreiben.

Der Relativsatz beschreibt "er":

> [...] [A]ls der Spieß **ihn, der er** gerade gehorsam Meldung machen wollte, einfach lässig weiterschickte, schämte er sich ein bisschen [...].

ist also ungefähr:

> Er wollte gerade gehorsam Meldung machen. + Als der Spieß ihn einfach lässig weiterschickte, schämte er sich ein bisschen.

Das geht mit allen Personalpronomen:

> Ich, die ich ihm am nächsten stand, habe ihn allein gelassen. 
> Dir, der du immer gelogen *hast*, wird nicht geglaubt werden.

Bei der ersten und zweiten Person ist das Personalpronomen nicht zu verdoppeln ungrammatikalisch; das zweite "ich" und das "du" können nicht weggelassen werden. Bei der dritten Person wird es sogar eher nicht verdoppelt, wie eine oberflächliche DWDS-Korpussuche nach [`er, @der`](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=er%2C+%40der&corpus=kern) ergibt.
Bemerke auch, dass im Relativsatz wegen des "du" "hast" und nicht "hat" steht; das Verb richtet sich also nach dem Personalpronomen.

Relativsätze für Personalpronomen sind ein stilistisches Mittel, um Sätze zu verschachteln, und eher in der geschriebenen als in der gesprochen Sprache anzutreffen und können etwas gestelzt klingen.

Comment: Das Personalpronomen im Relativsatz ist optional, wenn das Bezugspronomen in der 3. Person steht.